# Java tool to render dynamic HTML from a template without app server or expensive startup?

Tags: java, jsp, velocity, freemarker

This is going to sound odd, but we have a strange execution environment.  We want to be able to render dynamic HTML in it, but we can't have an app server like Tomcat or WebSphere.  Further, we want to offload as much work to the compile step as possible because caching is going to be of limited effectiveness.

We are considering FreeMarker or Velocity to render our HTML, but we're under the impression (from blog posts) that they can be expensive to parse and prepare each page the first time, and so best practice is to cache the parsed template.  In this execution environment, we fear we would pay that price often because caching the template is going to be problematic.

A wacky idea was brought up of precompiling JSPs, and then faking a call to the servlet they create with our own custom mock request and responses.  This has the nice feature of moving the heaviest lifting off to the compile phase of the app, meaning it should run nice and fast.  But it's got the disadvantage of being a bit hokey.

Can anyone suggest alternative tools/approaches?  A java tool to render dynamic HTML that does not require an app server and does not have an expensive startup?

Comment: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html ?

Comment: @Tschallacka - Unless I am misunderstanding what it does, I don't think so.  The idea is something that takes an HTML-sih template and converts it to an HTMl with dynamic elements added...like JSPs.  But with the limitation that I am not in an app server and can't cache effectively.

Comment: Ah... that's not rendering... that's parsing. Please rephrase your question to reflect that you wish to parse a parameterised html file into valid html. Maybe http://jtwig.org/ is something for you?